# Footnote mark in IEEETrans conference format

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, ieeetran, author

I need to add author note for a couple of author in a paper we are preparing using IEEETrans format. I used `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts` to allow me to use `\thanks`. However, while the text for the `\thanks` note is appearing in the footer the footmark is not appearing. How do I make the footmark symbols appear?

Comment: if you are still facing this issue, please provide a minimal working example so that we have something to work with. see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/117534)